# Passing values from radio button group to another page (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, radio-button

I have TestPage.xaml in which i run a test with questions. I have set maxCount=10 so when i have ten questions the test ends. I want to make a settingPage.xaml with 3 radio buttons 10 , 15 , 20 so when the user checks one of them to set the maxCount, it will store in IsolatedStorageSettings. But i can't figure out how to check in my TestPage.xaml which radiobutton is clicked, to know how many questions to load?

How can I achieve this without If-Else statements?

Comment: Post your code (both XAML and code-behind)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query string. When you navigate to `TestPage.xaml` pass in the max count value

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/TestPage.xaml?maxcount=" + maxCount, UriKind.Relative));
```

In your `TestPage.xaml` page, override the `OnNavigatedTo` method and check the query string value passed.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   string maxCount = string.Empty;
   if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("maxcount", out maxCount))
   {
      //parse the int value from the string or whatever you need to do
   }
}
```

Alternatively, you say you've stored it in isolated storage so you could also just read it back from that. The query string method would be faster but the isolated storage method will let you read it back at a later time if the user has closed the app.

Update based on comment

You can store a file that contains the data in Isolated Storage (you should add error handling)

```
using(var fs = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using(var isf = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("maxCount.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, fs))
using(var sw = new StreamWriter(isf))
{
   sw.WriteLine(maxCount.ToString());      
}
```

Then read it back

```
using(var fs = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
using(var isf = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("maxCount.txt", FileMode.Open, fs))
using(var sr = new StreamReader(isf)
{
   string maxCount = sr.ReadToEnd();
   //you now have the maxCount value as string
   //... 
}
```

Comment: Like u mentioned I want to use the isolated storage to keep the current state when the user reopen the app at a later time. I need to load the settings from the radio button that is clicked from my settings page.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example using isolated storage. I'm not on my dev machine so I can't test if it compiles but that should give you an idea of how to use isolated storage.

Answer (score 0):

See draw back here with isolated storage is it will take up a memory space even when you are not running the app. So while the app is running why don't you go ahead and save your options in `Application.Current.Resources` 
for example :

```
Application.Current.Resources.Add("Maybe Question section", 50); //will load 50 questions for particular section.
```

and while fetching

```
Application.Current.Resources["Maybe Question section"]
```

and then `tryParse` it to integer and get the number. this will be application wide until the app is running . You can fetch every time for a particular section. No need to connect to the isolated storage again and again to fetch or keep modifying files.

Comment: Nice approach, but what if I want to keep the current settings change every time the app is reopened by the user?

Comment: In case when it needs to persist when app is reopened use linq to sql to store in database. Heres the link msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202860(v=vs.105).aspx . Use files like images or pdf or others only to store to the isolated storage. For questions answers and other strings of data use linq.